# Magento, There are no products matching the selection

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, store, product

I have a problem about the display of products. So...in my Magento 1.9 i have more shop, then i have more subdomains.

```
store.siteweb.com
store2.siteweb.com
store3.siteweb.com
etc...
```

I wanted to create a new store, but in this case i'm not created a new subdomain, but a new section of the site. So my site will be

```
www.siteweb.com/store4
```

So the creation of this new shop has been so good. The only problem is when i write this line of code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="124" template="catalog/product/list_home.phtml"}}
```

for reclaim the products in my home page i get this message:

> There are no products matching the selection.

In my FTP i put the folder, containing the file index.php e .htaccess for subdomains, before of httpdocs. In this case, for the new store i put the folder inside the httpdocs. 
Then, in the creation of my home page, to recall products (already assigned and recalled in my shop) I pasted the code that I said above.

So, what could be the problem? A routing problem of the template?

Thanks so much.

Comment: try to refresh index management and cache management, it might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice man, i try this solution but the problem persist. Other solutions please?

Comment: Did you create a new store under already created website or a new website in magento

Comment: I created a new store under already created website. I had not assigned the attribute of the website to products. :)

Comment: So i found the solution of this problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What was the solution?